# How ImageMagick "sigmoidal-contrast" can be interpreted?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I could not find any good explanations of `sigmoidal-contrast` parameter. For example, if we have such a command:

```
$ convert -channel B -gamma 1.25 -channel G -gamma 1.25 -channel RGB -sigmoidal-contrast 25x25% 564.tif 564-adj.tif
```

What does this `25x25%` mean? What is the right syntax of this parameter? Can we have values like LxMxN%? Are these values - integer numbers only? Thanks!

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon on StackOverflow and I cannot add much to Anthony Thyssen's excellent description here... http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#sigmoidal

Comment: Thanks Mark! And don't you know - in real practice they set these two factors just looking vizually at the results, that they produce on the image? Or it is possible to calculate these factors from the initial image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer here is going to be quite subjective. As I said in the comments, there is an already excellent explanation by Anthony Thyssen [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#sigmoidal).

As far as I understand, there are two parameters which are:

- the amount of contrast increase, with 0 being least and 10 being most, and
- the centre-point about which to increase the contrast, which is on a scale of 0-100%, where 50% would increase the contrast centred around mid-grey (i.e. 128 on a scale of 0-255).

  convert input.png -sigmoidal-contrast `<AMOUNT>`,`<CENTRE>`% result.png

Let's look at the `<CENTRE>` value first. In general, you would want to draw a line of increasing contrast through the range of pixel brightnesses that interests you. The histogram is the easiest way I know of to determine where that is. So, if your histogram looks like this:

[image]

then I would suggest you use something like 25% for the `<CENTRE>` value. Whereas if your histogram looks more like this:

[image]

then you would probably want to set the `<CENTRE>` to 75%. So, in general, 50% is not an unreasonable default for the `<CENTRE>` parameter.

The `<AMOUNT>` parameter is going to be very subjective and vary from photo to photo. If, as I suspect, you are analysing satellite imagery, you can probably experiment to find a sensible value and then bulk-apply it to your images from the same series. I would start with 3-5 for normal photos maybe.

Comment: Great answer, as always! Thank you, Mark, for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the following sigmoidal curve between input (horizontal) and output (vertical axes:

[image]

-sigmoidal-contrast c1,c2%

c1 is the contrast or slope of the line at the midpoint. A c1 of 0 will be a straight line between lower left and upper right on the diagram. A larger c1 will make the slope or center part where it is straightest be more vertical.

c2 is the horizontal center point of the curve in the range 0 to 100% with 0% being shifted left so that straight part is on the left of the figure and 100% is shifted right so that the straight part is on the right.

You can see this from the diagrams of my script, sigmoidal, in terms of using the sigmoidal curve as a means of adjusting brightness and contrast with little clipping. See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/sigmoidal/index.php

Comment: It is very practical! Thanks!